# Capture what is selected in selectizeinput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to capture the what we have selected in selectizeinput (for example if we select 3, then 3 should be printed), but here, it goes on printing

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

init.choices <- c("Choose From List or Type New Value"="")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("foo", NULL, 
                 choices=init.choices,
                 multiple=FALSE,
                 options=list(create=TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "foo", choices=c(init.choices,  c(1,2,3)), selected = 3, server=TRUE)
    print(input$foo)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Put print(input$foo) in a different observe() ?

Comment: yeah same. I tried :)

Comment: it's working for me. What does it print for you ?

Comment: yeah got it.. Thanks. But i see first print is "" . Why?

Comment: Because initially there is nothing selected. Then it goes through the updateSelectizeInput and 3 is selected. But when you launch the app and create the selectizeInput, there is nothing selected, so it prints "".

Comment: If you want to print input$foo only after it has a value, you should write observe({req(input$foo);print(input$foo)})

Comment: Perfect and thanks

Comment: I summarised eveything in an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printing is wrong because you put `print(input$foo)` in the same `observe` than the `updateSelectizeInput`. Put it in a different `observe`. And if you only want to print when it has a value, and no `NULL` or `""`, you can add `req(input$foo)` before the print.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

init.choices <- c("Choose From List or Type New Value"="")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("foo", NULL, 
                 choices=init.choices,
                 multiple=FALSE,
                 options=list(create=TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "foo", choices=c(init.choices,  c(1,2,3)), selected = 3, server=TRUE)
  })
  
  observe({
req(input$foo)
print(input$foo)
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```